# VS2015 unmanaged debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vb6, visual-studio-2015, unmanaged

The shop where I work is currently using VB6 for development using controls and libraries.  Someone once showed me how to use Visual Studio to be able to debug this code by simply creating a console application in C# and then changing a few options.  He showed me this in VS2010, but I am now using 2015.  When I go into the project properties and go to the Debug tab, the option for "Enable unmanaged debugging" is not there.  Did Microsoft remove this option?  I have searched the web quite a bit, but have had no luck finding a solution.

Also, for kicks, I also have 2010 installed on my machine.  The option is available there, however when I attempt to run and debug I get a LoaderLock failure.  After researching it I found that I have to disable the exception in Visual Studio.  However, it would appear that my exceptions are locked down and I cannot change them as they are all greyed out.  I am an administrator on the machine I am using, but I am unsure of where or what I need to change to enable me to change the exception settings.

Any recommendations on either issue would be greatly appreciated.  It's not a show stopper for me, but a HUGE inconvenience.

Comment: The option is called `Enable native code debugging` in VS 2015, and is in on the `Debug` tab of the project properties under `Enable Debuggers`.

Comment: Also try right-clicking VS2015 icon and select `Run as Administrator` from the menu.

Comment: Yea, I had seen someone mention that before.  When I search the web however it says that there are differences between the two.  I noticed in the output window that it says "Module was built without symbols".  I have check to make sure that I did in-fact compile with creating the symbol (.pdb) file and that No Compression was selected.  As for the running as administrator, I always pin to the taskbar and set the properties so that it always runs as administrator.  Thanks for the comments though.